# How can I get the contents of a line up to the first occurence of a given string in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'd like all the characters of a line up until the first occurence of a search string.

Examples:

```
$ echo "onefootwofoothreefoo" | some_command_for_foo
one

 $ echo "123_456_789_" | some_command_for_underscore
123
```

I've been trying various things with sed and grep but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "onefootwofoothreefoo" | awk -Ffoo '{print $1}'

echo "123_456_789_" | awk -F_ '{print $1}'
```

bash only

```
f=onefootwofoothreefoo
echo "${f%foo${f#*foo}}"
```

Edit: As pointed out by @JohnB the following also works:

```
f=onefootwofoothreefoo
echo "${f%%foo*}"
```

Comment: Man, I was totally sleeping on awk. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnB Very true. I used that more than once this past week. Not sure why I didn't think of it now. "Stealing" it for my answer, thanks. =)